# custom app.config with installshield

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installation, installshield, installshield-le

I migrated from VS2010 to VS2012, my old installer projects were not compatible with VS2012 so I am working with InstallShield Limited Edition.

Now, I have this issue, 
in VS2010,
I was having separate app.config for each project.

DEV
- app.config

Prod
- app.config

Now, if I do the same, and build the installer,
the setup creates two files in the installation folder 
Progfiles/MyApp/app.config
and progfiles/MyApp/MyApp.exe.config

and my application takes the app settings from .exe.config file. How can I make my Dev installer to read from Dev/app.config file and Prod installer to read from Prod/app.config file.

Comment: You have two separate projects for dev/prod so why are you adding both the output in one single installer instead of two separate installers for prod/dev?

Comment: @PiyushParashar I am not adding both the outputs in one single installer, I have two separate installers.